# Create custom TimeZoneInfo based off another time zone

Tags: vb.net, timezone, offset

VB2012: I have data for two cities. The first piece tells me the time zone for city1 and the second piece tells me an hour offset from the first time zone for city2. Note that the offset is not relative to GMT but to the first time zone.

So something like:

```
Eastern Daylight Time, +4
```

I can get the time zone for the first city as so:

```
        'we get an actual TimeZoneInfo class
        Dim ct1TimeZone As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Daylight Time")
```

But for the second city I am struggling. I tried with the TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone but you are basically creating a time zone from scratch and the offset is based relative to UTC.

Comment: Is the offset constant, i.e. they go into and out of DST at the same time? This sounds like a very odd data set...

Comment: Its part of a bigger data stream that includes specific events. So we have an event and some info and part of that is the time zone info for two city pairs. it's only applicable to that line of data which is a specific event.

Comment: If it's only relevant for a single event, why do you need a `TimeZoneInfo` for it? Just use the one for the existing city, and then add the offset to get the local date/time for that event. It sounds like you *shouldn't* try to use it as a general time zone, as you only have information about the offset at one moment in time.

Comment: Because eventually I need to convert it to UTC time. This data has been this way for decades and there are two dates but only one has the time zone. the other has the offset. think of a trip departure and trip arrival.

Comment: If there are two dates then the data is already broken - because it's entirely possible that the two cities will change DST at different times, so the offset won't be the same. But you don't need a new `TimeZoneInfo` to convert it to UTC... if you know have the `TimeZoneInfo` for the other city, and the additional offset, just subtract the offset from the "city 2" local time (to get the "city 1" local time) and then you can convert that into UTC. Again there are issues around DST boundaries, but it sounds like that's the least of your worries...

Comment: Those are already taken care of by the system. the two dates are two points in time with the proper time zone for departure and the proper offset for arrival. DST has been considered for every event and for each date. I think I have something worked out. Ill test and post when its finished.